# Can't validate react-select using Formik with Yup

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I am trying to use formic and yup with react. In this project the selection button was created in a separate component using React Select. The attributes of the select tag are sending as the props. When I select an option in the selection tag, this error is occurred.

×
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Yup validation method

```
country: Yup.object({id: Yup.string().required('Please select a country'),}),
```

Initial data:

```
const formik = useFormik({
initialValues: {
    country: {}
  }
})
```

This is options

```
const countryOptions = [
{ id:"1", value: "india", label: "India" },
{ id:"2", value: "sri lanka", label: "Sri Lanka" },
{ id:"3", value: "us", label: "US" },
```

];

Using selection

```
<XSearchSelect
     label="Country"
     options={countryOptions}
     id="country"
     name="country"
     onBlur={()=>{
              formik.handleBlur({ target: {name:'country'} });
            }}
     onChange={(option) => {formik.setFieldValue("country",option.id);}}
     error={formik.errors.country}
     touched={formik.touched.country}
  />
```

Customized selection component

```
import React from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'

const XSearchSelect = ({ value, onChange, options, label,error,onBlur,id,name,touched }) => {

return (
    <div>
        <div className="block text-xaplink_gray_3 text-sm font-bold mb-2">{label}</div>
        <Select
            isClearable="true"
            value={value}
            options={options}
            onChange={onChange}
            id={id}
            name={name}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            theme={theme => ({
                ...theme,
                borderRadius: 5,
                colors: {
                  ...theme.colors,
                  primary25: 'silver',
                  primary50: 'gray',
                  primary: 'black',
                },
              })
            }
        />
        {touched && error ? (
     <p className='text-xs pl-2    text-xaplink_red_2 mb-4'>{error}</p>
   ) : null}
    </div>
)
}
```

export default XSearchSelect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have here is that you try to render your `error` here:

```html
<p className='text-xs pl-2 text-xaplink_red_2 mb-4'>{error}</p>
```

But it is an object, as you have described it in your initial values. You probably want to pass `error={formik.errors.country.id}` to your `<XSearchSelect />` component.

Or, as an another option you can just store country's ID as string in Formik, like this:

```js
const formik = useFormik({
initialValues: {
    country: ""
  }
})
```

This way you previous code should work some updates, adhering to the fact that you're storing ID as a string and not as an object now.